# One folder missing from Netbeans Project, its on disc though

Tags: java, netbeans

So I just opened a project, and while everything is working fine, I am unable to find one specific folder named as `protostar` inside "netbeans projects navigator".

I checked the file permissions and ownership, and even set the permission to 777 just to rule out possibilities. But this one specific folder (sub-directory) just doesn't seem to be read by `java` or `netbeans`.

I even tried creating that whole directory structure manually and deleting(renaming) the original. still the same strange phenomenon.

Then I thought I should check my excluded files list from the

`Options` > `Miscellaneous` > `Files` > `Files Ignored by IDE`

The value was:

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$|error_log|\\*.zip|\\*.tar
```

But here also I couldn't find any exceptions that would affect the visibility of that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after pulling my hairs for more hours than I'm comfortable sharing here, I tried resetting the excluded files list. and Voila! that whole directory just appeard, which meant I was onto something. And it almost certainly had to do with the "ignored files pattern".

And it hit me of trying to escape the period in the ".tar" inside the Regex Pattern.

```
...|error_log|\\*\.zip|\\*\.tar
```

..and rest is history. Smh.